# How to pass jwt token from one route to another?

Tags: flask, jwt, access-token, flask-jwt

I am new to coding. I have set up a login function within `Flask` using `flask-JWT`. Thus far, I am able to login (on "/login") and a token is generated using `jwt`.

However,  I have other routes which are also protected using a wrapper (@token_required). I would like to make it such that once users have logged in, the token will be passed to the other protected pages which they will then be able to access.

These are my codes:

wrapper to protect page

```
def token_required(f):                      #wrapper for token auth
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        token = request.args.get('token')

        if 'x-access-token' in request.headers:
            token = request.headers['x-access-token']

        if not token:
            return jsonify({'message': 'Token is missing!'}), 401
        
        try:
            data = jwt.decode(token, app.config['SECRET_KEY'], algorithms=["HS256"])
            current_u = User.query.filter_by(username=data['user']).first()    
            #identify user, otherwise, return error

        except:
            return jsonify({'message': 'Token is invalid!'}), 401
        
        return f(current_u, *args, **kwargs)   #previously return f(*args, **kwargs)

    return decorated
```

login route

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])        #login route
def login():
    auth = request.authorization

    if not auth or not auth.username or not auth.password:
        return make_response('Could not verify', 401, {'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm = "Login Required!"'})

    user = User.query.filter_by(username=auth.username).first()

    if not user:
            return make_response('Could not verify', 401, {'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm = "Login Required!"'})

    if user.check_password(auth.password): 
        token = jwt.encode({'user': auth.username, 'exp': datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=2)}, app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
        
        return jsonify({'message': 'hello ' + user.username}, {'token': token})

    return make_response('Could not verify', 401, {'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm = "Login Required!"'})
```

protected route using wrapper

```
@app.route('/protected')           #protected routes
@token_required
def protected(current_u):
    return jsonify({'message' : 'This is only for people with valid tokens'})
```

I am just stuck at this point in time as I can't quite find tutorials specifically for this / maybe its also an issue with not knowing what to search for. Could anyone help me out please?

Answer (score 0):

on further thougt I dont think using session is necessary as the authentication is encoded in the jwt token. I think you bug is in the decorator

```
try:
        data = jwt.decode(token, app.config['SECRET_KEY'], algorithms=["HS256"])
    except:
        return jsonify({'message': 'Token is invalid!'}), 401
```

This is except clause is to broad, what exceptions need to be handled here?

Comment: thanks for this! i was hoping if you may provide me a little more help.. where should i include these codes - within the wrapper? :) i tried it in the routes.py as a standalone function, within the wrapper, and also within the routes but none seemed to work :/

Comment: thanks! i missed out a line, which was to identify the user logged in as current_user, before throwing out the exception that all unidentified users will get the "token is invalid!" message. i have added that before the "except:" line. i also added that as an argument in the wrapper, as well as in the routes (e.g. def protected(current_u):). however, i'm still not getting the tokens passed automatically :/ what else could go wrong?

Comment: ^ to clarify, i meant to say i added it in the code in my main post! :)

Comment: are you passing the 'x-access-token' header in your client code?

Comment: could you explain what that entails please? the protected page simply returns a json message for now. (i was trying to set up something similar to this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WxGBoY5iNXY&t=1335s).

Comment: do we have to use API testing tools like Postman app (as with the tutorial) before we can pass the 'x-access-token' header, or are we able to do that in the script?

Comment: you need to pass the x-access-token header, you can use tools like postman for this or when you want to stay in python there is also the requests library